Save an Arrow Dataset or Pandas DataFrame as .bin and .idx files
I'm working with Hugging Face's datasets library to load a DataFrame using the from_pandas() method and save it as a Hugging Face dataset using save_to_disk(). The saved dataset consists of a folder with files data-00000-of-00001.arrow, dataset_info.json, and state.json.
However, I'm facing compatibility issues when trying to use this dataset with Megatron-LM (an accelerated version by Hugging Face, not NVIDIA's). Megatron-LM expects the dataset in .idx and .bin formats. The specific code causing issues can be found here.
Is there a method to convert a pandas DataFrame or a Hugging Face dataset into the required .bin and .idx formats? My DataFrame has multiple columns, if that matters, and contains around 100k records.
Edit:
I understand this is only necessary when using Megatron-LM indexed datasets/MegatronLMDummyDataLoader, and "normal" datasets can potentially be used, but it is recommended when datasets grow to extremely large sizes which will potentially happen in the future.

Have you read the Megatron README? It describes how to prepare the data.

@mudskipper Yeah it seems like they want a "loose" json format so I suppose that answers part of the question. It'd be converting a dataset into that first and then running their preprocess_data.py script https://github.com/NVIDIA/Megatron-LM/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#data-preprocessing also rad username
